# Wordpress - Posting Json encoded Array to PHP returns nothing/NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have several Inputs on my Plugins site. I gather the values of those and push them into an array. Then use the `jQuery.post` method to Post it to my PHP script.

Javascript:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(output); // output is an array with multiple strings
var data = {
    "action" : "add",
    "output" : json,
}
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
    console.log(response); // logs the response from PHP
})
```

PHP:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['output']);
update_option("option", $array);
var_dump($array); // returns NULL in console
echo $array; // returns nothing in console
wp_die();
```

I want PHP to return the array to JS and save it as the option.

This is my first Question here. Please feel free to give me tips on how to improve my question and code.

## Solution

It seemed to have problems with the '\' in the JSON String that was posted.

`$array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['output']))` 
did the job

Comment: Check in your network tab what the `var_dump($array)` dumps... and dump `$_POST['output']` as well to see what it actually contains.

Comment: It outputs "NULL" in the console, if that is what you mean....`var_dump($_POST['output')]` logs the Json string

Comment: No.. in developer tools you have a tab called "Network". Click on "Network" and then run your JS-script. You should then see the URL that's called (same as your `ajaxurl` contains). Click on that url and then "Response". That will give you the actual response from your PHP-script. Your `console.log` only shows you what jQuery returns, so if there are any errors or invalid format, you will get null.

Comment: I did that and it returns the same as `var_dump($_POST['output')]` , the Json String that i send with the request

Comment: and what does `var_dump($array)` output? Does it output an object or null? Could you post the content of `$_POST['output']`? (btw... your `echo  $array` will throw an error if the json_decode works, since you can't echo an object.). If you want the script to return the json object, then you should only do: `echo $_POST['output']`.

Comment: I posted an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It is written in the question under "solution"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script to return the same object as it got:

```
// The second param "true" makes sure we get an associative array
// instead of an object.
$array = json_decode($_POST['output'], true);
update_option("option", $array);

// Set the correct content header (good practice)
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Echo the string representation of the json-object
// Let's use the same as we got in the $_POST['output']
echo $_POST['output'];

wp_die();
```

Comment: Ok.. I'm sorry. I think I kinda gave you the wrong idea of my goal. The Goal of this is to set the option, so i can use it elsewhere. Returning the Object/String is just to control whether the script works.
`var_dump($array)` returns `NULL` . `$_POST['output']` contains a JSON String. I want to deserialize the JSON String into the original array and have that set as the option.

Comment: Yes, it was this sentence _"I want PHP to return the array to JS..."_ that gave me that idea.

Comment: Yeah sorry 'bout that. But still, thank you for trying.